# How to get a temporary html element resize using jquery when clicking?

Tags: jquery, resize, microsoft-metro, html

I'm trying to get a resize for divs or spans using jQuery, but only when you hold the left click button, like this example of `metro.js`:

http://www.claudiowebdesign.it/snippets/metro/

(I tried to read the `metro.js`, but I can't find the specific code that works)

Thank you

Comment: You have to use the "onmousepress/onmousedown" and "onmouserelease/onmouseuo" events in order to capture the moments when you want to change the size of your DIV

Answer (score 1):

You can resise your div on mousedown and mouseup. Example:

```
$('p').mousedown(function() {
    $('p').css('width', '180');
});

$('p').mouseup(function() {
    $('p').css('width', '200');
});
```

​on mouse down the element is 180px, on mouse up the element is 200px.

live:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5gsu/

As for the metro example, he uses 3d transforms. You can check that at http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp.

Comment: Using css you should add px to the size. Only when using the jquery .width and/or .height method you should use raw numbers.

Comment: You would say so, but as you can see in my jsfiddle, this works. JQuery adds px by itself.

Answer (score 1):

wrote this some time ago to scale an object. You're going to need jQuery for this to work.

```
changeSize = function(obj, size, time) {
    var left, r, top, _ref;
    _ref = obj.position(), left = _ref.left, top = _ref.top;
    r = obj.width() / 2;
    return obj.animate({
      left: (left + r - size / 2) + 'px',
      top: (top + r - size / 2) + 'px',
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px'
    }, time);
  };
```

this assumes that the object is positioned with absolute and is a square. If it isn't positioned absolute, just delete the left: and top: property changes. If the object isn't squared, you need to change it slightly (probably want to have a scaling factor, then, and just multiply `width()` and `height()` with that factor and write it into `animate` instead of `size`.

Comment: If you don't have it positioned absolute, then I guess it would make sense to increase the margin by the amount you scale down, so that you get the effect of the object 'sinking in', even when it is in a floating area. I can make you an example if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I found this nice jQuery Plugin: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Made a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub5nX/1/

code looks nice and tidy:

```
$('#clickme').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).transition({ scale: 0.9 }, 100)
});

$('#clickme').mouseup(function() {
    $(this).transition({ scale: 1 }, 200)
});
```

I like it, hope you do, aswell.